# Why my second line of "normal command" not work?

Tags: vimscript

here is my vimscript function, the first line of code is fine.
Add a " at begin of line.

But the second line of code is not work. The third line is shorter than the second line and it worked. Why this happens?

```
function! NormalTest()
    silent execute("normal! vip:normal! I\"\<ESC>")
    silent execute("normal! vip:normal! A;") " not work ; is not appended
    "silent execute("normal! vip") " this is work, vip select is done.
endfunction;
```

Comment: Your second command starts an Ex command (`:`) but doesn’t finish it with (_e.g._) `\<enter>`. Does that make a difference? (PS The semi-colon on endfunction will cause you problems.)

Comment: Hi do you know how to "@" a name? I try to @ your name with plain text but seems not work

Comment: If I type `@D` it completes to `@D.BenKnoble` for me, but it only works for one @-mention in a comment. You can't use @-mentions in post text, only comments such as these.

Comment: At any rate, I’m removed the (wrongly-formatted) answer from the post. Answers don’t belong in Questions.

Comment: Also, you can only @-mention people that have already interacted with a post in some way, and the completion doesn't work if the person you're @-ing wrote the question or answer you're commenting on, because they will be notified automatically anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second command starts an Ex command (`:`) but doesn’t finish it with (*e.g.*) `\<enter>`. As I’ve said before, though, the odd proliferation of `execute`/`normal` where they aren’t needed baffles me:

```
'{,'}substitute/^/"
'{,'}substitute/$/;
```

(PS The semi-colon on `endfunction` will cause you problems.)